# Exponential database relationship

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, social-networking

I’m developing under Symfony and Doctrine 2 and would like your advises regarding how to structure my database (mysql) for a  kind of social network platform for sharing information (articles). Keeping in mind  the large and increasing number of articles, the contrainst are that :
-   The author can share the article as many specific users from his memberlist
-   Any receiver could also decide to relay the article to specific users from his own memberlist
-   The member selection  for an author or receiver could be different for each article (target depend of its possible interest for the article)

A/ Article and User tables linked with a many to many relationship
I was first of all considering this architecture, but  the number of rows could be quite huge. Considering a user could have 1000 connections (members) , the number of row for only one article could reach a million of rows if some of his members decide to relay the article to others….

B/ Article table with a longtext column as relationship
I’m then considering to populate the article database with a text column that I would populate with the userID of the receivers… but again this column could get a million of IDs…. When a user will connect, I will then have to request a Select * Where UserIn IN  the longtext Column….

Would solution B could be suitable? How would you manage such a case ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have an articles table and user table.  You want to link articles to users.

The simple thing is to link them with a link table:

```
TABLE `Link` (
  `Article` ,
  `User` 
 )
```

Which is what you proposed.  There is no more efficient method.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. This was my first thought; but because of the number of users who can relay to others, it could exponentially reach a huge number of rows.... Lets say a user has 200 friends who all of them relay to their 200 friends each. I will have the :
Option A :

article-id | user_id
a            | 1
a            |...
a            | 200
b            | x
c            | y
a            | 210
a            | ...
a            | 40 000  (200x200)

Option B :

article-id | user_ids (in a long text column)
a            | 1,2,3,4....40 000
b            | x, x'
c            | y

Comment: In the end you still have to store the information somewhere.  No exponential.  Does not matter who refers the article, there is only one article and one user to link to.  No duplicates.  If you want to maintain the relationship with "relays", that is going to require more.  Maybe just add a referrer column if needed.